# Multiple keyboard shortcuts for Chrome extension's popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm working on a Chrome extension which is a client for the external bookmarking service. The extension does not synchronize native bookmarks: instead, it will have its own UI (there are reasons for that).

So, there are a few actions possible: adding a bookmark, getting (querying) a bookmark, and managing bookmarks. Each of those should have its own UI page.

I figured that an extension can't have more than one popup.html, so I decided to work this around by creating artificial tabs inside my popup, so that the user can switch between them. However, of course I also need to have keyboard shortcuts for at least these two actions:

- Add a bookmark
- Query a bookmark

E.g. Ctrl+D should open a popup with "add" tab activated, and Ctrl+Shift+D should open a popup with "query" tab activated.

But so far I failed to do that. Ideally, I'd like my popup to be invoked with some arguments, but it seems it's not possible. There is only one keyboard shortcut for opening a popup.

Then I tried to figure if I can define a command, handle it in the background page (e.g. adjust some internal state), and open a popup, which will read the internal state and will show the right tab; however, it turns out that I can't even show a popup programmatically. I can only use something like `window.open('popup.html');`, but it opens it in a new tab instead of a popup, so it doesn't really look good.

So is there a way to do that?

Comment: Show a real `popup` window via chrome.windows.create. I can't think of any other options.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That's just ridiculous that chrome's extension API does not allow that. Those real popup windows look ugly, compared to to the browser_action's popup.

Another option is to use content script and show dialog like this one http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ , but this is also very ugly. It's just a dirty hack.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger something on `ctrl + click on extension icon` or on `middle click on extension icon`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to specify multiple keyboard shortcuts for a Chrome extension popup (the `"_execute_browser_action"` command) and no way to programmatically open it.

You also can't press the same keyboard shortcut again and have the popup respond to it, which is one workaround I tried.  If the shortcut is <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>, you could imagine pressing it again to switch tabs within the popup.  But pressing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> while the popup is open will simply close it.  As far as I can tell, the event isn't passed to the popup code at all (not that you'd have much time to respond to it while the window closes).

The only semi-useful thing I found to do with this behavior is perform a different action when the popup's keyboard shortcut is quickly double-pressed.  In my [QuicKey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quickey-%E2%80%93-the-quick-tab-s/ldlghkoiihaelfnggonhjnfiabmaficg) Chrome extension, pressing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> once opens the popup, but pressing it twice quickly (within 500ms) will switch to the previously used tab.  So you can sort of get two actions out of one shortcut.  (It does this by calling `chrome.runtime.connect()` as soon as the popup opens.  The background page listens for `chrome.runtime.onConnect` and notes the time.  If it gets an `onDisconnect` event within the time limit, it switches to the previous tab.)

The one other nugget I've been able to wring out of Chrome extension popup behavior is that your code, if it adds an event listener early enough, will get the `keyup` events when the user releases the modifier keys of the shortcut.  So if they press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to open the popup, you'll get a `keyup` event for the <kbd>alt</kbd> key.  In my case, that was enough to provide some useful functionality: pressing <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> opens the popup, then, while keeping <kbd>alt</kbd> down, pressing <kbd>W</kbd> (right next to <kbd>Q</kbd>) navigates through a list of tabs, and releasing <kbd>alt</kbd> switches to the selected tab.  It's as close as I could come to the <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd> behavior of Firefox within Chrome's constraints.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger something on `ctrl + click on extension icon` or on `middle click on extension icon`?

Comment: Not AFAIK. Clicking the toolbar icon with any combination of modifier keys simply triggers the `_execute_browser_action` command, causing the extension's popup to open. There's no way to check the current down state of any modifier keys after the popup opens. As I mention above, the one thing you can do is try to listen for the `keyup` modifier event in the popup, but that would require the user to wait for the popup before releasing the `ctrl` key, which isn't really how people expect ctrl-clicks to work.